# how can the view model know which view instance change?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a UserControl that I would like to instantiate multiple times. I am trying to use the MVVM approach. For instance, in MainWindow.xaml

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GroupBox x:Name="Default Transition" Header="Global Transitions" MaxWidth="500">
            <uc:TransitionsForm x:Name="GlobalTrans"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="Slide Transition" Header="Slide Transitions" MaxWidth="500">
            <uc:TransitionsForm x:Name="SlideTrans"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

The first instance is the default transition to use if the slide transition is not defined.

My ViewModel is called TransitionViewModel. I connect the view model to the UserControl in xaml as

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="cbTransStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="14,5,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Content"/>
    </Style>
    <tranconv:KeyValConverter x:Key="KeyValConvert"/>
    <vm:TransitionViewModel x:Key="TransVM"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

then I set the DataContext in the Grid of the UserControl.

```
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource TransVM}">
```

My question is how can the view model know which view instance changed? I could add an event handler in MainWindow but that does not sound like an MVVM approach. If I can access the view name, that would work, too.

Comment: "*how can the view model know which view instance changed?*" - not at all when the UserControls have their own, private view models. Controls should never have private view models, but instead operate on the view model object provided by value inheritance of the DataContext property.

Comment: What do you mean by " but instead operate on the view model object provided by value inheritance of the DataContext property."

Comment: Do I make a viewmodel for each instantiation, then?

Comment: Both controls could operate on the same view model instance, which would be assigned to the DataContext of their common parent element, i.e. the MainWindow. The value of the DataContext property is inherited by child elements, so the controls' DataContexts would hold the same object as the MainWindow's DataContext. See [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Comment: Thanks Clemens for the clarification. Thanks especially to Rekshino for the code sample. That clarified a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in comments you should instantiate sub-viewmodels in main viewmodel and bind to them. It can be something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public TransitionViewModel GlobalTrans { get; set; } = new TransitionViewModel();
    public TransitionViewModel SlideTrans { get; set; } = new TransitionViewModel();
}

<Window x:Class="...">
    <Window.DataContext>
       <vm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <GroupBox x:Name="Default Transition" Header="Global Transitions" MaxWidth="500">
            <uc:TransitionsForm x:Name="GlobalTrans" DataContext="{Binding GlobalTrans}"/>
        </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox x:Name="Slide Transition" Header="Slide Transitions" MaxWidth="500">
            <uc:TransitionsForm x:Name="SlideTrans" DataContext="{Binding SlideTrans}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Don't forget to remove setting the `DataContext` in `UserControl`, it mostly must come from outside.